# Setup shipping charges for two different Stores based on country selection

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, multistore, store-view, ce-1.8.1.0

I have to one website which contains two different stores. I want to set different shipping charges for the both stores.

Magento Provide different shipping charges per website. but I need to create different shipping rules for both store.

**`STORE A Shipping Details`**

```
Minimum order value € 50 net - shipping charge 
Germany:
- Minimum order value € 50 net
- Ship € 6.30 net
- Free shipping from 100 € net
- 5% discount from 250 € net

Abroad Austria:
- Minimum order value € 50 net
- Postage to weight
- Free shipping from 250 € net
- 5% discount from 250 € net
- Calculate No VAT

All other foreign:
- Minimum order value € 50 net
- Postage to weight
- 5% discount from 500 € net
- Calculate No VAT
- International prices"
```

**`STORE B Shipping Details`**

```
Germany:
- Free shipping from 150 € net

Abroad Austria:
- Parcel postage to weight

All other foreign:
- Parcel postage to weight
- International prices
```

If anybody faced this type of changes then please help me.

Comment: I've done a lot with shipping in Magento before, and from experience I can tell you it would be a lot easier (and more professional) to just create separate websites for each store. With that being said, there are hacks that you can use. Can you explain what options you want for Store A and which ones you want for Store B. Also, can you make sure that the stores are actual "stores" and not just "store views" (which would be like for translations).

Comment: I know this one if I create two website then it's easy for but I want this one because if I creating two website then I can not add two store products into one cart .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start of, this is not possible on storeview level, only on website level. And all extensions I know that can do this work also on website level. I've never tried to get this to work on storeview level but I guess there's a reason why all extensions work on website level.

So, if you can change your shops architecture to website levelmost of this stuff you should be able to do with the free [Webshopapps Matrixrate](http://www.webshopapps.com/eu/free/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html) extension. It allows you to set up rules similar like **`table rates shipping`** but way more advanced.

If, for some reason, it does not provide all functionalities you need you can upgrade to the paid version of that extension. That one can do literally anything when it comes to shipping rules.

Comment: I will test and let you know @sander Mangel. :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Did some further checking. For the 5% reduction part I think you'll need either the paid extension or use cart price rules. If you need help with the CSV for the shipping rules, you know where to find me ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can of course develop something yourself, but I would go with

[fooman surcharge](http://store.fooman.co.nz/extensions/magento-extension-surcharge.html).